# Accessability of private fields in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I know that if a instance variable of a class is made `private` then it is not accessed directly by the object.

But in the following code,something as such is happening,and the code is running fine!

How is `b` able to directly access length,breadth and height?

```
public class Box {
    private int length,breadth,height;
    Box(int a,int b,int c){
        length=a;
        breadth=b;
        height=c;
    }
    Box(Box b){
        length=b.length;            //These lines!
        breadth=b.breadth;
        height=b.height;
    }
    int volume(){
        return length*breadth*height;
    }
}

public class BoxWeight extends Box{
    public int weight;
    BoxWeight(int a,int b,int c,int d){
        super(a,b,c);
        weight=d;
    }
    BoxWeight(BoxWeight b){
        super(b);
        weight=b.weight;
    }
}
class apples
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        BoxWeight mybox1=new BoxWeight(10,20,30,40);
        BoxWeight clone=new BoxWeight(mybox1);
        System.out.println(mybox1.volume()+"...."+mybox1.weight);
        System.out.println(clone.volume()+"...."+clone.weight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method

Comment: "I know that if a instance variable of a class is made private then it is not accessed directly by the object." What do you mean by that? Your question is quite unclear (and appears to have rather more code than you need to demonstrate the problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the argument is of the same type. In java an object can access private members of other objects of the same type. Thus in this case `Box` can access any private members of the `Box` class, even in different objects.

Answer (score 1):

`private` means that the fields (or inner classes or methods) are not visible outside the class (meaning to any other type). However as `b` is of the same type `Box`, this restriction does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

`Private` is inaccessible for *other* classes; `b` is also of type `Box`, so it is in its own home!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, a Box object can access privates of Box **inside the Box class**.